# Node.js async/await in non-async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

I just can’t understand how to do this function synchronously?

```
function (value) {
    const img = (async () => {
        const image = await base64Img.requestBase64(value);
        return image;
    })();
    return img;
}
```

In result I have a promise `Promise { <pending> }`, but I need result there. Please help :)

Comment: `async`/`await` are tools to manage promises. `async` functions *always* return a promise. You cannot turn asynchronous code into synchronous code. Creating a `async` function that awaits a promise and then returns its value is pointless. Just use the promise you get from `requestBase64` directly.

Comment: but I don't need to use it directly, I have to return it from main function :(

Comment: You. Can. Not. Do. That.